# Dropzone doesnt load unless page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js in a rails application. The dropzone is part of a form with other input elements. At page load the div containing the form is hidden. On the click of a button, that div slides down. However, at this stage Dropzone is not initialized. But it works absolutely fine if I refresh the page and click the same button again.

This is my dropzone function (inside `document.ready`)

```
function dropzoneControl() {
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        url: '/the_url',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 5,
        maxFilesize: 3,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        init: function() {
            dzClosure = this;
            document.getElementById("submit-button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                dzClosure.processQueue();
            });

            //send all the form data along with the files:
            this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("name", $("#name").val()); * * other data * *

            });

            //on successful upload
            this.on("successmultiple", function(file, responseText) {
                $('#name').val(""); * * clear the rest of the form * *
            });

            this.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
                this.removeAllFiles();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with the dropzone options outside the `ready()` funtion, this should solve the problem. Or you can initialize the dropzone manually once the page is loaded with the constructor, take a look at http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically, don't forget to set `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false` before is you use this second option.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was turbolinks. The dropzone wasn't working when I came to the page from another page. But worked when I refreshed it directly. Added `data-no-turbolink` to the div containing the link to the page, and it works great now.

Comment: Updated syntax: `data-turbolinks="false"` https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links